# Cognos issue with conditional page display

Tags: cognos

I'm trying to make a page display conditionally based on a prompt in Cognos 10.1.

I have a prompt page with a dropdown that is populated by a query named PromptSQL.  PromptSQL returns a table with two columns, Value and Descr.  The Value Prompt on the prompt page has had the following properties altered:

```
Query: PromptSQL
Use Value: Value
Display Value: Descr
Parameter: Location
```

I created a boolean variable, vShowPage, to determine if one of the report pages, Page 2, should be displayed.  The code under vShowPage is simply:

```
?Location? in ('12', '15', '20')
```

So, I only want the "Page 2" page to be printed if the location selected is 12, 15 or 20.

I then selected "Page 2" under Report Pages and associated vShowPage to the Render Variable property.  When I validate the report I get the following error:

> RSV-VAL-0032 The following expression is not valid: ?Location? in
>   ('12','15','20'). If the item exists in a query but is not referenced
>   in the layout, add it to a property list. CRX-API-0005 An error
>   ocurred at or near the position '0'. The variable named '?Location?'
>   is invalid.

I also tried changing the variable to a String Variable, but listing all of the possible values will be problematic.  But even the small test I did using the String Variable resulted in the same error.

I tried adding PromptSQL to the Query property of Page 2 and checking the Value column under the Properties property.  I even tried checking Value and Descr.  These all produced the same error.

I used this link from IBM's web-site as my template for doing this: [How To: Hide a report page based on a prompt](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21342081)

Any help figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the prompt value ?Location? in the conditional expression.  Use ParamDisplayValue('Location') or ParamValue('Location') instead, e.g.:
ParamValue('Location') in ('12','15','20').